# Can I send a custom event, or call another method, in another class but not wait for the result?

Tags: java, android

I would like to send a custom event (or call another method) to another class and not wait for the response?

The best way I can explain it is to use the Windows SDK method.  It gave you the ability to "post a message to another window" (WM_POSTMESSAGE).  The thing about that feature, which is the part I want, is that the message went into the OS's msg queue.  So you did not have to wait for the response, your app could continue on.

So is I have a method in class A that is doing something, and at some point it wants to emulate an OnClick event in class B, but not wait for the result as the method still has more to do.

Is this possible?

Sorry for the long winded question.

Comment: post the code....

Comment: Sure just put the code that calls the method inside a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html), which I believe resembles the most what you are seeking.

Contrary to what advised in the comments, I do not feel starting a `Thread` to call a method is a good pattern here.

---

Have your sender send a signal via the aforementioned component:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(FILTER_VALUE);
// put your data in intent
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

where

```
public static final String FILTER_VALUE= "com.you.yourapp.MY_SIGNAL";
public static final IntentFilter SIGNAL_FILTER = new IntentFilter(FILTER_VALUE);
```

Whoever is meant to receive the signal shall implement a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
this.localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Do what you have to do here... call you method
    }
}
```

If you are using `Android`'s framework classes (Activity, Fragment, Service, ...) you should follow the standard life-cycle pattern for registering and un-register the receiver:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // Listen if someone sends data
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(this.localBroadcastReceiver, SIGNAL_FILTER);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // I'm going to the background / or being destroyed: no need to listen to anything anymore...

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(this.localBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

otherwise registering it when the object is initialized should be the way to go.

I believe this is the `messaging` system you are looking for.

Comment: This looks like what I want.  But the receiver never gets anything.  The code is too long to post here.  Is there another way to add to my question to show the code?

Comment: @PlasticProgrammer yes post just the relevant classes, how they are initialized, and how you register and expect the signal. take out everything else

Comment: in my main activity I just put 
`        this.localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                boolean bResu = true;
            }
        };'       

Then in another class
`final Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(String.valueOf(SIGNAL_FILTER));
                        boolean b = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);`

I never end up in receiver

Comment: @PlasticProgrammer apologies my example wasn't very correct. You shouldn't do `String.valueOf(SIGNAL_FILTER)` as it doesn't return the `IntentFilter` value. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help but am getting no msg.  No errors, but no msg received.

The one thing I'll say is that I'm sending from a different class and the line:

`LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity.getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);`

Is weird. It won't let me  AndroidStudio makes activity final, which I don't understand.  But I look with the debugger and the values are the same.  I even tried it substituting a context value and passing getApplicationContext() from main class.

No errors, just no msg received at all.

Comment: @PlasticProgrammer it's better of you update your question with the relevant code. At same time you should explore on this website why some functions require variables to be final. There is a particular reason for it

Comment: In my MainActivity
`    BroadcastReceiver localBroadcastReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        this.localBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {@Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                boolean bres = true; }};`

Then in another class

final Intent intent = new Intent();LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
                        intent.setAction(FILTER_VALUE);`

Comment: took a new route & added a new class & made it my receiver. In mainactivity I registered it be notified of any WiFi updates. When I run my app, then turn Airplane mode on/off, my app gets the notification. Now I just need to be able to register it to receive custom notifications, which I can't.

Here's how I register it now, 

`BroadcastReceiver br = new MyReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(br, filter);`

Comment: , I need to move this to a new question but I do have it somewhat implemented.  Thanks

Comment: @PlasticProgrammer. I agree, the matter is getting out of context. Still, you do not need to accept my answer if it did not help you. But I do appreciate anyway

Comment: No, your answer was thee correct way, I thank you @MarkoPacak.  Just saying I can so far implement only half of it.  Was letting you know how I was able to determine that the receiver part works. So my problem is the syntax to broadcast a "custom" event, and register the receiver for custom events.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run some code that will run in parallel while your current code is running, the easiest way to do this would be using a Thread. A thread once started will run in parallel and will not block your application, thus allowing the code that started the thread to continue executing even while the code in the thread is also executing.

To create and use a thread, use the following code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//put the code that you want to run in parallel here

 }       
});  
 thread.start();
```

You should be warned though that using parallel programming without carefull planning may result in very weird results especially if two different threads are accessing and changing the same variables or data. You should therefore plan your code very carefully if you plan on using multi threading.